# SSD doesn't want to install MacOS on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, installation, ssd, macos-sierra

I swapped an old HDD on my MacBook Pro 13 mid 2012 with a Crucial MX300 275GB, I formatted the SSD with the extention "OS X Journaled", Actually, I followed all the right ways to prepare the SSD to be installed.

However, during the installation everythings stoped working here:

[image: Photo of a MacBook screen with macOS installation]

I made the USB pen with Mac OS Sierra correctly because I used it even in other Mac's with any problems.

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: I think you forgot to include a question in your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into your USB Pen drive, then open the disk utility, click Disk Utility, click on your SSD, click erase, then click macOS Extended Journaled (Non-sensitive) on a GUID Partition map, if you used Master Boot Record, there is a high likelyhood that it will fail.

Best of luck.

-- For next time, you might get faster results on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) portion of the site.